# How do I select max from a count?

Tags: mysql

I was trying to select the Band with the highest Albums number, as an error it shows

> Unknown column 'N_Albums' in 'field list'

What shoud I do in order to see the name of the band and its albums number?

```
select Name, max(N_Abums) as `Albums`  
from (select a.Name, count(b.CodDisc) as `Nr`
    from `S8.Band` a join `S8.Album` b
    where a.CodBand = b.CodBand
    group by a.CodBand) as Test
```

Comment: Are you sure that N_Albums is the correct column name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `N_Albums` to `Nr`.

You aliased the count with `Nr`, so that's what you have to take the max() of.

```
select Name, max(Nr) as Albums
from (
    select a.Name, count(b.CodDisc) as Nr
    from S8.Band a
    join S8.Album b on a.CodBand = b.CodBand
    group by a.CodBand
) as Test
```

I also improved your join syntax and removed all backticks as they were unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Order the result accordingly and take only the first record

```
select a.Name, count(b.CodDisc) as `Nr` 
from S8.Band a 
join S8.Album b on a.CodBand = b.CodBand 
group by a.CodBand, a.Name
order by count(b.CodDisc) desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for `MAX`, just `ORDER BY <COLUMN> DESC` and get the first line.